# Kotlin: Retain, replace or remove each map entry in-place

Tags: java, dictionary, kotlin, functional-programming

I have a mutable map (a `LinkedHashMap` to be specific) in Kotlin. For each map entry, I want to conditionally perform one of three actions:

- Retain the entry as-is
- Replace the entry's value
- Remove the entry

In old Java, I would probably use an `Iterator` over the map's `entrySet()` for this purpose (using `Iterator.remove()` or `Entry.setValue()` accordingly). However, I wondered if there is a more elegant, functional approach present in Kotlin to do the same (i.e. apply a lambda to each entry in-place, similar to using `replaceAll()`, but with the ability to also remove entries).

---

In Kotlin, the following combination of `replaceAll()` and `retainAll()` does the same thing:

```
val map = LinkedHashMap<String,Int>(mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 3))
map.replaceAll { key, value ->
    if(key.startsWith("a")) {
        value * 2
    } else {
        value
    }
}
map.entries.retainAll { entry ->
    entry.key.startsWith("a") || entry.key.startsWith("b")
}
```

However, this iterates the map twice and requires splitting up the predicate/transformation. I would prefer a `compute()`-style all-in-one solution, just for all entries.

Comment: can you please share an example of what you want to a sheave ?

Answer (score 4):

In functional world, immutability is an essential principle. So in-place modifications are not convenient.

But if you prefer an in-place approach, possible options are `retainAll` or `removeAll` to filter items. For in-place replacement you need to iterate the collection. You can use `forEach` to do an in-place modification:

```
data class User(var name: String)

val users = mutableListOf( User("John"), User("Alice"), User("Bob") )
users.run {
    removeAll { it.name == "Alice" }
    forEach { it.name =  "Mr. ${it.name}"}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the immutability remark - the map in question may become large, hence I would like to avoid unnecessary copies. Ideally I am looking for a `compute()`-like solution, i.e. a single lambda to decide value replacement or removal

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example how you can do all operations in a single expression:

- Using `filter{}` we keep only elements that fit particular conditions, here: with a value >= 200. The result of this filter is a new map.
- Using map we transform a map from previous step into a new collection. When transforming, we change some values, some remain unchanged.
- Using `toMap()` we transform the resulting collection into a new map.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, Int>()

    map.put("a1", 101)
    map.put("a2", 102)

    map.put("b1", 201)
    map.put("b2", 202)

    map.put("c1", 301)
    map.put("c2", 302)

    println(map)

    val result = map.filter { (key, value) -> value >= 200 }.
        map { (key,value) -> 
                if (value >= 300)   Pair(key, value * 100) 
                else                Pair(key, value)
    }.toMap()

    println(result)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this uses more than one lambda and does not perform the changes in-place

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can write like this

```
fun main() {
    val map = mapOf(
        "test1" to 1,
        "test2" to 2,
        "test3" to 3
    )
    val resultMap = map.mapNotNull { (key, value) ->
        when (value) {
            1 -> null // remove
            2 -> key to 4 // replace
            else -> key to value // retain
        }
    }.toMap()
    println(resultMap) // print {test2=4, test3=3}
}
```

Comment: While this neatly resembles `compute()`-like remapping, it does not perform the changes in-place - temporary collections will be created

Answer (score 1):

This version is in place (similar to what would you write in java) but not with functional approach

```
 val map: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf(
    ("a" to 1),
    ("b" to 2),
    ("c" to 3),
)

val mapIterator = map.iterator()
while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
    val mapEntry = mapIterator.next()

    when (mapEntry.key) {
        "a" -> mapIterator.remove()
        "c" -> mapEntry.setValue(mapEntry.value * 2)
        else -> println("retain this  entry")
    }
}
```